# Meta viewport not sizing correctly

Tags: css, viewport, meta

I'm a relative newcomer to CSS, and I recently figured out how to use `@media` to query for a device or browser size, and help make the site responsive, but I've been having a lot of trouble with the `<meta name="viewport">` tag (as I see a lot of other people have too).

The shift to the mobile view triggered by `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 680px)` is working just fine, but so far, on both iPhone and Android phones that I've tested it on, the initial view is partially zoomed in.  For the mobile view version, I have the body, the container div, and the child elements sized at 540px or less and then used the following tag in the head of the html doc:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
```

But like I said, when I visit the site on a mobile device (like my Razr M, which has a screen resolution width of 540px), the viewing area shows up zoomed in, so that what I see is about 2/3rds of the full 540px of content, starting from the left.  But then, if I manually zoom out, it stops at the correct size and everything looks good.  The test site is up at http://thereisnomountain.com/indextest.html, and it relies on one stylesheet at http://thereisnomountain.com/style/tinmtest.css.  Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Change your media query to @media (max-width: 680px)

Comment: UPDATE: I hadn't tried this, apparently, but if I visit the site on a smart phone in landscape mode, it sizes perfectly (and then when I flip it back up to portrait, it's still sized correctly).

Comment: @JoeConlin That doesn't seem to make a difference